# Finding a bound for $[G:N]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of finite index in $G$. Then can I find a subgroup normal $N$ of $G$ such that $N\subset H$ and $[G:N]$ is finite? Further, I would like to find an upper bound on $[G:N]$. I would a appreciate a hint.

Comment: Such that $[G:N]$ what?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the notion of normal core of a subgroup. For a reference, see http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_core .

In particular it is characterized by the property that it is the kernel of some action $$\rho : G \to \operatorname{Sym}(G/H)$$
where $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ denotes the symmetric group over a set $X$.

Now suppose that $[G:H]=n$; by the first isomorphism theorem you have
$$G/ \ker \rho \cong \operatorname{Im} \rho \le \operatorname{Sym}(G/H) \cong S_n$$
hence $[G: \ker \rho] = |\operatorname{Im} \rho|$ divides $|S_n|=n!$.